# Code for sharing the result of the app on clicking a button ?

Tags: facebook, share

This is my app : https://apps.facebook.com/whatareyouinlife/

You can see it automatically upload image and texts after seeing the result, i want to give the users a choice whether to post or not..So i want to make it only share the result after clicking a button which will put near to the result page..

How do i do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a link (ssstyled as button) with a format like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
```

You will find more information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ (Direct Url Example)